# When to stop making tests in TDD

Tags: tdd

I develop Tetris game using TDD. For now I'm testing isEmpty() method for Field class.

I have alredy written three test cases:

```
@Test
public void shouldIsEmptyMethodReturnTrueForEmptyField() {
    Field field = Field.createStandartEmptyField();
    assertTrue(field.isEmpty());
}

@Test
public void shouldIsEmptyMethodReturnFalseIfCellInLowerLeftCornerIsFilled() {
    Field field = Field.createStandartEmptyField();
    field.fillCellAt(0, 0);
    assertFalse(field.isEmpty());
}

@Test
public void shouldIsEmptyMethodReturnFalseIfCellInLowerRightCornerIsFilled() {
    Field field = Field.createStandartEmptyField();
    field.fillCellAt(field.getWidth() - 1, 0);
    assertFalse(field.isEmpty());
}
```

And my isEmpty() method looks like this

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (isFilledCellAt(0, 0)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (isFilledCellAt(getWidth() - 1, 0)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So I can farther write new test cases to test every combination of filled cells in tetris field. **When I have to stop? What is the right way to test isEmpty() method of tetris Field class using TDD?**

Comment: There is no "right" way. If you are finding defects in the code under test (especially as you add features) then you don't have enough tests; but other than that this is subjective and down to experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Equivalence partitioning](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/what-is-boundary-value-analysis-and-equivalence-partitioning/) can help you reduce the number of test cases to write. Here, you could for instance have 3 cases : [NoCells, OneCell, ManyCells].

[Boundary Value Analysis](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/what-is-boundary-value-analysis-and-equivalence-partitioning/) is a complementary approach, although it is more applicable to methods that take free input. Here, the context doesn't really allow going below or beyond extreme edges (-1 cells or > than number of cells in a row).

If you really want to test combinations of cases, [Property-based Testing](http://blog.jessitron.com/2013/04/property-based-testing-what-is-it.html) or other automated test data generation methods might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is largely based on experience, and there's no easy way to determine your answer. When writing tests I look at:

1. Coverage. Have I covered *all* the code paths ? Or at least those that I feel will be the potential cause of issues
2. Inputs and outputs. Have I covered *all* the likely combinations of inputs and outputs. In some scenarios, this is not going to be practical (e.g. if your method takes an integer to add to another, do you pass in 1,2,3....)
3. Edge cases. Does my code handle *boundary* conditions properly ?

So as I write my code, I have a feel for the problematic scenarios that I need to assert, and whether each line of code I've written is covered in some fashion. If I have a sizable number of input/output scenarios to cover, I would consider implementing a table of inputs/outputs to assert on and let the test framework exercise each in total (e.g. Groovy's [Spock](http://code.google.com/p/spock/) makes this very easy. Junit's [Parameterized Tests](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm) is another implementation of this)

Answer (score 0):

This will largely be a personally preference. However if you want to follow strict TDD, then you will want to stop once you can no longer write a broken test. You start by writing a test that fails, and write exactly enough code to pass that test. Then you write the next failing test and continue to update your code and refactor until everything is green. If you can no longer write a failing test, then you don't need to write anymore tests.